# Completely nuked my libdrm2 package, need help

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I was attempting to downgrade my libdrm2 package via dpkg, as it was a recommended fix for issues I was having with HTML5 video acceleration (I was getting 100% cpu usage on all cores when viewing even 720p video). This resulted in a problem with dependencies, so I have since updated back to version 2.4.67-1. 
Now this is what apt reports:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core gcc-5-base:i386 gksu gnome-exe-thumbnailer icoutils
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386
  libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libbsd0:i386 libcapi20-3
  libcapi20-3:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386
  libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgd3:i386
  libgif7:i386 libgksu2-0 libglapi-mesa:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
  libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
  libllvm3.8:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmirclient-dev libmircommon-dev libmircookie-dev libmircookie2
  libmpg123-0:i386 libnettle6:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libprotobuf-dev
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libpulse0:i386 libqt5concurrent5 libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsm6:i386
  libsndfile1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
  libtasn1-6:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx3:i386 libwayland-dev
  libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-dev libx11-doc libx11-xcb-dev
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau-dev libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-0:i386
  libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-sync1:i386
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1:i386 libxcb1-dev libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage-dev
  libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp-dev libxdmcp6:i386 libxext-dev libxext6:i386 libxfixes-dev libxfixes3:i386
  libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon-dev libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386
  libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence-dev libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxxf86vm-dev
  libxxf86vm1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 p11-kit-modules:i386 p7zip qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools
  unixodbc wine-gecko2.21 wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-mono0.0.8 winetricks x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

System info: Ubuntu 16.04, i3-wm, compton window compositor, Thinkpad X220 i7, using Intel graphics.

Comment: Please don't add your solution to the question itself. Post an actual answer instead.

Comment: Apologies, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Purged libdrm2, reinstalled libdrm2, rebooted, and all is well with the apt dependency warnings. Interestingly it also solved my 100% cpu usage on HTML5 video. If anyone else is having issues with libdrm2 on a similar platform, my guess is a dpkg-reconfigure would solve it.